# JAVA:Merge the multiple properties files

Tags: java

I had the multiple properties files in Folders and subfolders and I need to merge the properties files which are in root folder and its subfolders.

Please check the example of folder structure and contents of files to be merged.

I have tried the below code it is merging two files but could not append the name as above.

```
    public class Test {

static void loadCommon(Properties merged, Path dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new FileInputStream(dir.resolve ("common.properties").toFile()));
    merged.putAll(p);
}

static void loadTest(Properties merged, Path dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    for (File f : dir.toFile().listFiles(file -> file.getName().startsWith("dd")))
        p.load(new FileInputStream(f));
    merged.putAll(p);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path rootDir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("root");
    Path testDir = rootDir.resolve("AB");
    Properties merged = new Properties();
    loadCommon(merged, rootDir);
    loadTest(merged, rootDir);
    loadCommon(merged, testDir);
    loadTest(merged, testDir);
    merged.list(System.out);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Please anyone can help me on this

Answer (score -1):

To make it work the way you want you should follow this to order:

```
load common.properties
merge test2.properties
merge AB\common.properties 
merge AB\test2.properties
```

but in the files you merge you should never repeat a key that has a value that is identical to one already loaded, only put keys with more specific values.

So I used this input:

```
RootFolder: ---------------------->Subfolder:AB-->                 
common.properties                                 common.properties       
  key1=common key value 1                           key2=common key value of AB
  key2=common key value 2
test2.properties                                   test2.properties
  key1=test2 key value 1                              key3=test2 key value of AB
  key2=test2 key value 2                             
  key3=test2 key value 3
```

with this code:

```
public class Test {

    static void loadCommon(Properties merged, Path dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(new FileInputStream(dir.resolve ("common.properties").toFile()));
        merged.putAll(p);
    }
    
    static void loadTest(Properties merged, Path dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        for (File f : dir.toFile().listFiles(file -> file.getName().startsWith("test")))
            p.load(new FileInputStream(f));
        merged.putAll(p);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path rootDir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("root");
        Path testDir = rootDir.resolve("AB");
        Properties merged = new Properties();
        loadCommon(merged, rootDir);
        loadTest(merged, rootDir);
        loadCommon(merged, testDir);
        loadTest(merged, testDir);
        merged.list(System.out);
    }
}
```

it returns:

```
-- listing properties --
key3=test2 key value of AB
key2=common key value of AB
key1=test2 key value 1
```

please note that I merged all the files with name "test*.properties" if you want to use a single file change loadTest()

Comment: should it be generic depth or always two level depth?

Comment: it has to be upto level 5 and could you please suggest me in the code and file name doesn't start with test.Filename can be starts with anything

Comment: I need to add the output files in the target path....could you please suggest me to add into target folder which is output file generating for each sudfolders

Comment: you should clarify what you want: how many files you want to generate and what to merge

Comment: each level contains one file or more, beside common?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219534/discussion-between-user1708042-and-yadi).

Comment: more files with common...it will be 5 files with different name like dd-omit,dd-post,dd-pst